# as.numeric returns NA for majority of values in column in R

Tags: r

I'm practically a total beginner but anyway - trying to convert column values to numeric values.

If I go:

`head(df$Average.Amount)`
returns: "1,646.15" "1,425.00" "2,487.50" "2,200.00" "2,456.25" "2,412.50"

`class(df$Average.Amount)`
returns: character

`head(as.numeric(df$Average.Amount))`
returns: NA NA NA NA NA NA

I tried noquote to take away quotations...

Let me know what you think!

Comment: `"1,646.15"` isn't a string that can be converted to a number, because of the `,` thousands separator.

Answer (score 1):

As @thelatemail says, your `as.numeric()` doesn't work because of the commas. Luckily, you can use `readr::parse_number()` for the  same task.

```r
numbers <- c("1,646.15", "1,425.00", "2,487.50", "2,200.00", "2,456.25")

as.numeric(numbers)
#> Warning: NAs introduced by coercion
#> [1] NA NA NA NA NA

readr::parse_number(numbers)
#> [1] 1646.15 1425.00 2487.50 2200.00 2456.25
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>